# TinyMCE: trigger event only when clicking outside the entire editor

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I am integrating TinyMCE (jQuery edition) into a very legacy system (think pre-AJAX). One of the requirements is I need to reload the page when the user clicks outside the editor (don't ask... assume it's needed for now).

I have this working when the user clicks outside the Iframe editor. However, the TinyMCE toolbar buttons are outside the editor too, and certain ones (involving drop-downs or modal windows) also invoke the 'blur' event.

Is there a work-around, or an alternative event I can use? I've crawled through the TinyMCE docs, but there doesn't seem to be a hook covering the entire editor.

I have put together a [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mnNy2/) at http://jsfiddle.net/mnNy2/ with instructions on how to see the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can have id's for the Elements & put all textarea elements

then in myfunc(e)

you can get the id of the Element Clicked by using `var id=e.target.id` and then apply conditions accordingly that **if any element in textarea is clicked** `e.preventDefault()`
**else** `alert('changed);`

This should work.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply use this :

```
$('body').click(...);
```

Comment: this will fire when the toolbar is clicked!